I want to use GraphQL to create a database in the SAAS platform for customers
I have a working GraphQL schema to create new databases but was looking for a more efficient way to build the schema in GraphQL. I would like to avoid creating 100 plus fields by hand and was wondering if there is a way to maybe use Excel and a program to interpret the fields and types into the GraphQL schema?
mutation createDataSet {
    createDataSet(
        createDataSetInput: {
            name: "temporary demo audience - delete later"
            type: AUDIENCE
            attributes: [
                { name: "firstName", type: TEXT, mapAs: FIRST_NAME }
                {
                    name: "emailAddress"
                    type: TEXT
                    identifyAs: { channels: EMAIL }
                    category: "Contact information"
                }
                { name: "lastName", type: TEXT, mapAs: LAST_NAME }
                {
                    name: "PhoneNumber"
                    type: TEXT
                    identifyAs: { channels: SMS }
                    category: "Contact information"
                }
            ]
        }
    ) {
        dataSetId
    }
}

